# How to start Google-Assistant-Demo on boot in /etc/rc.local on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi2, google-assistant-sdk

I'm struggling with al the answers I have found till now, but nothing seems to work on my RPi.
I want to start google-assistant-demo on boot.

In created script named `google_start.sh` with:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/env/bin/
source activate
google-assistant-demo --device-model-id XXXXX &
```

Make it executable: `sudo chmod +x google_auto_start.sh`

In my /etc/rc.local I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash -e        
printf "Start Google Assistant\n"
/home/pi/google_auto_start.sh

exit 0
```

When I reboot it comes with the following error: argument --credentials: No such file or directory
It looks somehow in the `/root/.config/google-oauthlib-tool/credentials.json`. Which doesn't exist. That file is under de /home/pi dir.
I already gave the --credentials as params with the g-a-demo command, but it can't run either.

What do I mis here? It shouldn't be so hard I think to run a script on boot, without user interaction.
Maybe run script as 'pi' user solve my issue.

Comment: I'd see if you can either change the user running the script or copy over your credentials file.

Comment: Ok, but how do I run that "google_auto_start.sh" script in /etc/rc.local as pi user?